# How to change textbox class in angularjs while typing and checking condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am trying to change textbox class at run time, if item.value is >10 class `success` will apply otherwise class `danger` will apply

Here is the code I am using.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
<td>{{item.name}}</td>
<input type="text" ng-model="item.value">
</div>
</div>
<!-- 
<input ng-class="{'success': {{item.value > 10 ? true : false}}, 'danger': !{{item.value > 10 ? true : false}}}" type="text" ng-model="report.attribute_result">
-->
```

And

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{name:'abc',value:10},{name:'xyz',value:8},{name:'lmn',value:15}];
}
```

And here is jsfiddle for this : http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/3452/

Please guide me to fix this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use the `ng-class` attribute as follow:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="item.value" ng-class="{'success': item.value > 10, 'danger': item.value <= 10}">
```

See updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/3453/).

Answer (score 1):

Inside `ng-class` there is no need `{{item.value > 10 ? true : false}}` or something like that.
http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/3454/

```
ng-class="{'success': item.value > 10, 'danger': item.value <= 10 }"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the input as this

```
<input ng-class="(item.value > 10)?'success':'danger'" type="text" ng-model="report.attribute_result">
```